# How to use i18n-js with webpacker in rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just switched to Rails 6 (6.0.0.rc1) which uses the Webpacker gem. I want to use i18n-js in some of my modules for translation purpose. How can configured i18n in my application with webpacker ?

Comment: I assume you'd like to scroll down to https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js#usage to section where it is explained usage without Asset Pipeline as that's the case with Webpacker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for the late answering but I have already resolved this issue as below :-

```
yarn add i18n-js
```

After this I have changed in below files

```
## javascript/packs/application.js

require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

window.jQuery = window.$ = require('jquery')

var Turbolinks = require("turbolinks");
Turbolinks.start();

import I18n from 'i18n-js'
window.I18n = I18n
```

And then to load all translations :-

```
## application.html.erb

<script>
   var language = "<%= I18n.locale %>";
   I18n.translations = <%== I18n::JS.filtered_translations.to_json %>;
</script>
```

Now translations are ready to use in js files:-

```
I18n.t('a.hello')
```

Comment: I wound up going with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

The right way is to follow this guide:

Gemfile

```
gem 'i18n-js'

bundle --binstubs
$ yarn add i18n-js
$ bin/rails webpacker:install:erb
```

app/javascript/i18n-js/index.js.erb

```
import I18n from "i18n-js"
I18n.translations = <%= I18n::JS.filtered_translations.to_json %>;
export default I18n
```

app/javascript/packs/application.js

```
import I18n from 'i18n-js/index.js.erb'
console.log(I18n.t('hello'))
```

Source:
https://gist.github.com/bazzel/ecdff4718962e57c2d5569cf01d332fe

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @10Rep Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted the locale of `I18n` JS module to be changed by setting the Rails `I18n.locale` in application controller (the standard Rails way of managing locale).

I managed it to work just by adding the `gem "i18n-js"` and running `yarn add i18n-js`. I tried to avoid `bundle --binstubs` and `bin/rails webpacker:install:erb` since i thought i wouldn't need it.

Added in `app/javascript/packs/application.js`:

```
// Import i18n-js and make I18n module available on views
import I18n from 'i18n-js'
window.I18n = I18n
```

Added before closing body in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`. Tried to put it in head but i'm using Turbolinks and it didn't work.

```
<script>
   I18n.locale = "<%= I18n.locale %>";
   I18n.translations = <%== I18n::JS.filtered_translations.to_json %>;
</script>
```

App running with:

- rails '6.1.3'
- ruby '2.7.2'
- i18n-js '3.9.0'
- yarn.lock says: i18n-js 3.8.0